# How to resolve this Xcode Server Bot Integration Error?

Tags: swift, xcode, continuous-integration, bots

I am new to CI. I am trying to integrate. I am using Xcode Server & Bots btw. I have followed this tutorial:

[Xcode 10 CI- Medium](https://medium.com/xcblog/xcode-server-with-xcode-10-124013cbedbc)

So, when I integrate I get this error:

[image: Errors]

As you can see these are the errors which I am getting. I do not have these pods now as I have removed both these pods. Why does it give me errors?

When I started developing I pushed pods to the `source control` and now, these a days I just push the `Podfile` and not the pods. Is this the reason? How can I resolve it?

And, if everything goes well, what will happen when I integrate like the new code will add up in my Xcode, like when we `pull`?